# How do I breed a sun dragon in DragonVale?

Tags: dragonvale

I already got a moon dragon by breeding a chrysalis dragon and a galaxy dragon together! How do I breed a sun dragon? anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you'll need to take in order to be successful in your breeding:

1. > Go to your breeding cave or the epic breeding island. Your park
   >   needs to be at level 10 or higher before trying to breed this
   >   dragon. Tap on the breeding area to make it glow.
2. > For a successful outcome, the elements of Cold and Lightning need to
   >   be present, and as such, there are numerous possible combinations of
   >   breeding pairs. Some suggestions for the many possible combinations
   >   include:
   >
   > ```
   > Firefly dragon with a Cold dragon
   > Blue fire dragon with a Crystal dragon
   > Ice dragon with a Quake dragon
   > Cold dragon with a Storm dragon
   > Fire dragon with a Storm dragon
   > Scorch dragon with a Cold dragon
   > ```
3. > Wait 48 hours for breeding. The egg color will be gold with a sun icon
   >   in the middle.
   >       Breeding time can be hastened by spending gems.
4. > Put the egg into nursery and wait another 48 hours until it hatches.
5. > Place the Sun Dragon in a sun habitat. To help it grow, feed it the
   >   same food as all baby dragons.

[source](http://www.wikihow.com/Breed-a-Sun-Dragon-in-DragonVale)